# How to put code onto objects in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object

I am trying to create a kind of simple game where you move a player around and dodge some enemies. I was wondering if it was possible to add code onto a object in as3.

I want to be able to put code onto an object and not on the main timeline, so when it is on the stage, it will carry out the codes.

Sorry if this is confusing, I don't know how to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not put code on the timeline.

Read a tutorial about Object-Oriented Programming in AS3. Learn about Document Classes and how to attach a class to a library object.

Here's a link to one of the first tutorials that popped up when I googled "Flash oop tutorial": http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-oop-introduction-basix--active-5789

Answer (score 1):

Each MovieClip object has its own timeline. Create a layer for code in your object's timeline and add actionscript in the usual way to it -- using the Actionscript panel.

You can start with a simple 'trace' statement to see that it works.